# C++ counting odd numbers from list

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a program using C++ in which the user should enter 10 integers and the number of odd numbers are diplayed to the user.  For example, the user enters: 7,26,44,3,78,3,24,66,25,90,12 and the output would be "there are 3 odd numbers in the list".

I can't seem to find what i did wrong.  Any help is very much appreciated.

Here is my program:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{   
    int limit;
    int counter;
    int sum;
    int number;
    cout<<"Enter 10 digits:"<<endl;
    cin>>limit;
    counter=0;
    sum=0;

    while (counter < limit)
    {
        cin>>number;

        counter++;
        if (number%2==1)
            sum++;
    }

    cout<<"the number of odd numbers are"<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: i can't seem to find what i did wrong - Can you elaborate on that?  What is wrong with the program? Should it be how many odd digits there are in a 10 digit number?

Comment: i have no idea how u cam up with this logic

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: it should work, but your code is slightly misleading, you should cout<<"Enter limit of digits:"<<endl; before cin>>limit

Comment: You haven't specified what the input looks like.  Your program will indeed work if the input consists of 10 digits separated by spaces, tabs, and or newlines.  If you're reading 10 consecutive digits, `cin>>number` will read the whole thing as single int value, losing leading zeroes and producing garbage if the result is >= 2^31.

Comment: I take back the part about leading zeroes if you don't need the entire digit count that you put in `counter`.

Comment: Man that would take a long time to enter 1000000000+ `int`s

Answer (score 3):

Your code is wrong inside the while loop. Writing `cin>>number` in there makes no sense. You have already taken the 10 digits you wanted. Your while loop currently asked the user for inputs `N` number of times, where `N` is equal to the 10 digit number entered.

What you aim to do, is to extract a digit from your `int limit` and check if it is even or odd. Here is the modified code for that:

```
while (limit != 0)
{
  int digit = limit % 10; // extract last digit of limit
  limit = limit / 10; // remove last digit from limit
  if (digit % 2 == 1) // check if digit is odd
    sum++;
}
```

EDIT: As pointed out by MikeHousky, long long should be used to store the 10 digit number. It would make more sense to take the input in the form of a string, and then manipulate the string.

Comment: You could also use `while (limit != 0)` to control the loop so it would on any size number.

Comment: The while condition is wrong, and this won't work if the first digit is 0, It also won't work if 3 or more on a machine where an int is 32 bits or less.

Comment: Thanks for that. Edited the while loop. @MikeHousky, could you please explain the second part of your comment?

Comment: @NathanOliver Never mind about leading zeroes, since he's counting digits but not using the sum.  If you try to read 3123456789 into a 32-bit int, you'll get an overflow.  You'll need a wider number type to avoid reading a char at a time.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you tell the user to, "Enter 10 digits:" which I take to mean a 10-digit number. And then you loop until they've entered that number of digits. So if I entered 1234567890, I would be there for the rest of my life entering numbers.

Maybe something that accepted `int`s until the user entered a non-`int` would make more sense:

```
cout << "Enter numbers, to quit type: exit" << endl;
cout << "the number of odd numbers are " << count_if(istream_iterator<int>(cin), istream_iterator<int>(), [](int i)->bool{return i & 1;}) << endl;
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan. I have realized i made a serious mistake in my question and therefore it wasn't clear to many of you. What i meant in the question is that the user should enter 10 Integers instead of 10 digits.

Answer (score 0):

The write solution to your question is:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()

{

int sum;
int digits[10];

cout<<"Enter 10 digits:"<<endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    std::cin >> digits[i];

sum=0;

for (int j = 0; j < 10; j++)
{
    if (digits[j]%2==1)
        sum++;
}

cout<<"the number of odd numbers is: "<<sum<<endl;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).